# How to disable SMS notification programmatically by contact (phone number) on android

Tags: android, android-activity, sms, uri

Currently, as we know that, we can disable sms notification on android by reaching to App info and uncheck "show notification" .

[image]

However, supposing that I only want to disable SMS notification by specific phone numbers.

So how to solve this case with android code?

Currently, I am also looking for the best way to do it but I still don't have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create BroadCast Receiver. e.g.

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
                android:priority="999" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

There in the  `MyReceiver.onReceive()`, if you call `abortBroadcast();` detecting the desired contact no, then it should suppress the status bar notification.

### WARNING:

But as far as I know, starting from KK you can't abort `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast for security reasons. Before KK, it should work.

Comment: I tried to use abortBroadcast but we don't have a good result :(. Do you have any example for this ?

Comment: Thats the only thing I know to abort SMS notification before KK.